# MongoDB: Create array of arrays from array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a problem which I have already solved with $unwind and $group, but I am really interested in whether it is possible to solve with $reduce.
Currently using MongoDb 3.4

Here is the input:

```
{
 "myArray": [
   {"foo":"x",
    "bar":"y",
     "important": {
           "imp_1": "a",
           "imp_2": "b"
      } 
    },
    {
    "foo":"x",
    "bar":"y",
     "important": {
           "imp_1": "aa",
           "imp_3": "bb"
      } 
    }
 ]
}
```

And here is what I would like to achieve:

```
{
 "myArray": [
   {"foo":"x",
    "bar":"y",
     "important": [
           {"k":"imp_1", "v":"a"},
           {"k":"imp_2": "v":"b"}
      ]
      } 
    },
    {
    "foo":"x",
    "bar":"y",
     "important": [
       {"k":"imp_1","v": "aa"},
       {"k":"imp_3","v": "bb"}
      ] 
    }
 ]
}
```

Is it possible to solve it with 1 $reduce?
My problem is, that it created only 1 "important" array, instead of 2 for each object in the initial array.

Is $reduce at all better then a $unwind, $group and a $project right after each other?

Thx & Regards,
Grunci

Comment: If your version is specifically 3.4.4 you can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) otherwise you might need to bump to 3.4.4 or 3.6

Comment: @chridam But here we have nested array right? In the mongo docs its saying **"If the argument is a document that itself contains embedded document fields, the $objectToArray does not recursively apply to the embedded document fields."**

Comment: @RahulRaj You can use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to iterate the nested array elements in `"myArray"` and apply the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator in the in option